# IN SQL, do joins in a view definition act as if enclosed in parenthesis when combined with other joins

Tags: sql, join, view

For example suppose you have tables A, B, and C, where

```
A LEFT JOIN B JOIN C
```

will produce different results than

```
A LEFT JOIN (B JOIN C)
```

and suppose you create a view BC, where that view is defined as B JOIN C.

Is the query

```
A LEFT JOIN BC
```

guaranteed to be equivalent to `A LEFT JOIN (B JOIN C)`?

I've tried this out using PostgreSQL 9.3 and found that it does behave this way. However I'd like to know if this is specified by the spec. I'd also like to know if all SQL implementations behave this way.

(Edit: perhaps a more useful way to state my last question would be: does anyone know of any database implementations that do not work this way, or know from experience that most of them do?)

Answer (score 1):

yes and yes and yes :)

**A LEFT JOIN BC guaranteed to be equivalent to A LEFT JOIN (B JOIN C)?**

yes, imagine your first join as:

`a * b + c`

you're changing it to `a * (b + c)` - of course you have different result

then you're doing:

```
bc = b + c;
a * bc;
```

**However I'd like to know if this is specified by the spec**

cannot find link to actual standard, but here is link from oracle documentation: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ansi-iso-sql-support.php

> Multiple Joins: The SQL: 1999 standard assumes the tables are joined from the left to the right

**I'd also like to know if all SQL implementations behave this way**

so, all databases which are supporting ANSI SQL will behave the same way

Comment: I don't see any reference to views in that Oracle page you linked. And of course I can make the deduction that if the spec dictates this then databases that support the spec will do so. But in reality that is not a useful deduction because no database implementation supports the spec fully they all deviate here and there.

Comment: @EricS view is the table or at least you can suppose it as table